# ARKit and Vuforia - marker recognition

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia, arkit

I'm working on an iOS app, I need to recognize a marker (most likely it will be QR code) and place some 3D content over it using ARKit.

I was thinking about a combination of Vuforia and ARKit.

**Is it possible to use Vuforia only to recognize the marker and get its position, and then "pass" this data to ARKit?**

- I need to recognize the marker in order to select corresponding 3D content.
- I need to get the position of the marker only ones, in order to place 3D content there, after that I want to use ARKit for tracking.

Is it possible?
Is there another solution for marker recognition which can be used with ARKit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1: 
You can handle the recognition of the marker (called Image Target in Vuforia)
Create a script:

```
public class CustomTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour,
                                           ITrackableEventHandler
{
    ...

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                    TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                    TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            OnTrackingFound(); 
            // **** Your own logic here ****
        }
        else
        {
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can replace the DefaultTrackableEventHandler with this this script.

[image]

Q2: I need to get the position of the marker only ones, in order to place 3D content there, after that I want to use ARKit for tracking.

You can add an empty game object to be the child of the marker (ImageTarget), and the hierarchy would be:

```
YourMarker(ImageTarget)
     |__EmptyPlaceHolder
```

When the marker is recognised, you can then programatically get its location:

```
var placeHolder = GameObject.Find("EmptyPlaceHolder");
if(placeHolder != null){
    Debug.Log(placeHolder.transform.position); // all the location, localPosition, quaternion etc will be available to you

}
```

Comment: Where does the above UI come from? I don't see anything like it in the Target Manager or in Xcode.

Comment: Drag an image target prefab to the scene, you will see it then.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It seems to be a perfect solution, but for some reason, it doesn't work for me. Here is a short example code I created, so if I detect a marker I want to show a simple UI canvas with a button. http://csharppad.com/gist/82e2573f674f1d42b413d3fb8b0b9b60 I disabled the DefaultTrackableEventHandler, and added Debug.Log() for testing, but I don't see any messages in my console (so OnTrackingFound() never reached), but I still see objects, parented to the image prefab appear when the marker is recognized! It's strange did I made a mistake anywhere? I use Unity 2017.2.0f3

Comment: Are you able to see Debug.log in other places, e.g. start() ? Did you hide the log/error panel? From the code, if you see the toggled UI, it is a signal that OnTrackingfound() is fired.

Comment: @Rumata I am also looking for similar solution. Were you able to crack this?