# How can i combine image based tracking (like vuforia) with google ARCore?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to build an app with unity using vuforia and ARCore or ARKit but using both is not supported. Is there another image-based tracking software I could use instead of vuforia?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing. What i figured out [ARKit and Vuforia - marker recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761440/arkit-and-vuforia-marker-recognition#new-answer)

:Try to use Vuforia and ARKit separately. First get your tracking information from Vuforia, stop Vuforia and turn ARKit on.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising! I'll see if i can use it.