# iOS - ARKit + Vuforia : Convert Vuforia Coordinates to ARKit Coordinates

Tags: ios, opencv, augmented-reality, vuforia, arkit

I want to detect the marker using Vuforia and place a 3d object on it. From then I want to use the ARKit in my application. How do I know the ARKit world transform for the detected marker or 3d object?

I am using same view controller to initialize ARKit SceneView and to start Vuforia Engine. I have gone through this [unity solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761440/arkit-and-vuforia-marker-recognition). I am not too sure this works. Also, I need this to be developed in native iOS Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: Did you see new image recognizing features of `ARKit` [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ARKit 1.5 Beta upgrade, markers can be detected and tracked with the ARKit camera itself. So there is no need to use Vuforia engine to detect the marker. My requirement can be implemented without using Vuforia now.

Comment: Venkatesh can you please tell me, how ARKit detect specific marker. What I learned with ARKit is, It's not marker base AR, rather it shows a object in world co-ornate system that is fixed in the real world coordinate. It doesn't behave like vuforia that always marking and tracking a or multiple object simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Vuforia matrix to SCNKit Matrix using this method -

```
- (SCNMatrix4)SCNMatrix4FromVuforiaMatrix44:(Vuforia::Matrix44F)matrix {
    GLKMatrix4 glkMatrix;

    for(int i=0; i<16; i++) {
        glkMatrix.m[i] = matrix.data[i];
    }

    return SCNMatrix4FromGLKMatrix4(glkMatrix);
}
```